# Why use CfnAppSync rather than AppSync in CDK project?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

We need to add new JS resolvers to our API, and phase out the VTL resolvers, for an AWS AppSync CDK project built with Cfn<> Cloud Front CDK, like this:

```
          let resolver = new CfnResolver(this, `${r.typeName}_${r.fieldName}`, {
            apiId: graphql.attrApiId,
            typeName: r.typeName,
            fieldName: r.fieldName,
            dataSourceName: r.dataSourceName,
            requestMappingTemplate: readVtl(reqPath, contextVariables),
            responseMappingTemplate: readVtl(resPath, contextVariables),
          });
```

The latest examples here [AWS CDK Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/using-your-api.html) all use the following AppSync CDK directly in this style.

```
new appsync.Resolver(this, 'pipeline-resolver-create-posts', {
      api,
      typeName: 'Mutation',
      fieldName: 'createPost',
      code: appsync.Code.fromInline(`
          export function request(ctx) {
          return {};
          }

          export function response(ctx) {
          return ctx.prev.result;
          }
  `),
      runtime: appsync.FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
      pipelineConfig: [add_func_2],
    });
```

I am struggling to get the CfnResolver to accept new JS resolvers. I have tried as many variations of below as I can and looked [here for AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/appsync/CfnResolver.html)

```
          let resolver = new CfnResolver(this, `${r.typeName}_${r.fieldName}`, {
            apiId: graphql.attrApiId,
            typeName: r.typeName,
            fieldName: r.fieldName,
            dataSourceName: r.dataSourceName,
            code: readJs(reqPath, contextVariables),
            runtime: CfnResolver.AppSyncRunTime.JS_1_0_0 <-- DOESNT WORK
          });
```

Can someone suggest either what I'm doing wrong or whether I should give up the Cfn CDK and move to direct AppSync CDK? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, using L2 constructs is the way to go most of the time, only use the L1 Cfn constructs if you can't achieve what you need with L2. If you must go with L1, just check the docs for CfnResolver to see what its runtime prop expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `runtime` syntax is incorrect in your `CfnResolver`.  Use the [FunctionRuntime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync.FunctionRuntime.html) utility class to set the runtime name (`APPSYNC_JS`) and version (`1.0.0`) in one shot:

```js
runtime: FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
```

As @gshpychka says in the comments, though, you are almost always better off using the L2 [Resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync.Resolver.html) construct.  The `Resolver` constructor creates a [L1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) `CfnResolver` resource under the hood, but provides better DX.  For example, you can put your resolver code in a separate file and reference it with [Code.fromAsset('path/to/code.js')](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync.Code.html#static-fromwbrassetpath-options), which enables better support for [linting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-reference-overview-js.html#utility-resolvers), [testing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-reference-overview-js.html#test-resolvers) and [Typescript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-reference-overview-js.html#additional-utilities).

Comment: Much, much appreciated @gshpychka and fedonev. That makes MUCH more sense.